# Trying to use JavaScript to clear a text field

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to clear a text field and it does not work. I get the alert but it does not clear it. What am I doing wrong?

This is a generic function that can be call on any text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

             function clearThis(target)
            {
                alert('before...' + target.value);

                if ($(target).value == "Search  ")
                {
                    $(target).value = "set to something else";   
                    $(target).style.color = '#000000';
                    $(target).style.fontStyle = 'italic';     
                }
                else
                {
                   $(target).value = "";
                }

                alert('after...' + target.value);            
            }           

    </script>         

    <title>My page</title>

</head>

<body>
   <div class="historysearch">
      <input id="username" type="text" value="Search  " onclick="clearThis(this)"/>                              
   </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The value is `"Search  "` (note the extra spaces), is this what you intended?

Comment: `$(target)` is jquery object. You should be using `$(target).val()` to get and `$(target).val("")` to set. As well as `$(target).css()` to apply styles

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `$` would suggest that you are using JQuery but you arent including the library in your page.

If you *are* using jQuery, use the correct jQuery way to get and set values ([.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)) and styles([.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)). And of course, include the jQuery library...

```js
function clearThis(target) {
  alert('before...' + target.value);

  if ($(target).val() == "Search  ") {
    $(target).val('set to something else');
    $(target).css({'color':'#000000', 'font-style': 'italic'})
  } else {
    $(target).val('');
  }

  alert('after...' + target.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="historysearch">
  <input id="username" type="text" value="Search  " onclick="clearThis(this)" />
</div>
```

If, in fact, you *aren't* using jQuery, you need to omit the `$()` syntax from your code..

```js
function clearThis(target) {
  alert('before...' + target.value);

  if (target.value == "Search  ") {
    target.value = "set to something else";
    target.style.color = '#000000';
    target.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
  } else {
    target.value = "";
  }

  alert('after...' + target.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="historysearch">
  <input id="username" type="text" value="Search  " onclick="clearThis(this)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks..i was mixing up the 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
function clearThis(target)
        {

           // alert('before...' + target.value);
           //alert(target);
            if (target.value == "Search  ")
            {
                target.value = "set to something else";   
                target.style.color = '#000000';
                target.style.fontStyle = 'italic';     
            }
            else
            {
               target.value = "";
            }
            //alert('after...' + target.value);            
        }
```

HTML code

```
<div class="historysearch">
   <input id="username" type="text" value="Search  " onclick="clearThis(this)"/>                              
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you need to update in your code first one is you should add jquery.js file and second one is if you want change value go through id or class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

             function clearThis(target)
            {
                if (target.value == "Search  ")
                {
                    $("#username").val("set to something else");   
                }
                else
                {
                   $("#username").val('');
                }

                alert('after...' + target.value);            
            }           

    </script>         

    <title>My page</title>

</head>

<body>
   <div class="historysearch">
      <input id="username" type="text" value="Search  " onclick="clearThis(this)"/>                              
   </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

`$(target)` is jquery object and not js so `value` could not be accessible

You can do like this(js) :
`target.value` 
or 
Like this (jquery)
`$(target).val()`

Answer (score 0):

To Clear the textbox value using JQuery, Use following Line:

$(control).val("");